# Laravel return empty array after stored procedure call

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I have the following code

```
 $values = [1, "2018-08-10", "2018-08-11"];
 $data = DB::select('exec SP_NAME ?, ?', $values);

 dump($data);
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NAME]
@Opc int,
@FechaIni nvarchar(20)=null,
@FechaFin nvarchar(20)=null
AS
BEGIN
    if @opc=1
    begin
        SELECT * from table where convert(date, datetimeField) between @FechaIni and @FechaFin
    end
END
```

If I execute my query on MSSQL Server everything works fine. When I execute the SP from Laravel there is no error message, just an empty array.

Testing and playing with the code I found that the problem is when I'm sending more than one parameter, for example I change my select query for this:

```
SELECT * from table where convert(date, datetimeField) between '2018-08-10' and '2018-08-11'
```

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I think you forgot an extra `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Laravel but it looks like you're creating a value array with 3 values but you're only sending 2 parameters in your query.  Should it maybe be

`$data = DB::select('exec SP_NAME ?, ?, ?', $values);`

You don't get an error from SQL Server because you define `@FechaIni` and `@FechaFin` as optional parameters.

Comment: That's correct, I think that after solving another errors I forgot to add that parameter haha thanks!